# Problem using yarn to start a react application

Tags: reactjs, hadoop-yarn, web-frontend, npm-start

Hello first of all I'm quite new to React so sorry for my ignorance.
Here is my problem I am trying to run a app using the command `yarn start` but I am always getting an error.

This is what I'm trying to run and the commands that I have used:

`git clone https://github.com/francoborrelli/spotify-react-web-client.git`
`cd spotify-react-web-client`
`yarn install`

then

`yarn start`

This is the error that it show

`
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "start-js" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`

I've also tried to execute with `npm start` but it's the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay thanks I was able to fix it just had to change a line in my package.json file
now when I use yarn start does not shows the error.